# How to create a Regular Expression that only captures words that are constructed by repeatedly appending substring (i.e ab) of a word?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to create a regular expression that captures a word phrase repetition.

Example:
Given the word "ababab".
Given the phrase to be repeated, "ab"

The regular expression should return true because the given word is constructed by repeatedly concatenating "ab"

Here is what I have so far:

```
(ab)+
```

The problem is that this will return true even for strings like "ababba", but it shouldn't

Comment: If you need exact regexp, add "^(ab)+$" making sure that it spans beginning to end.

Comment: @Mulli Oh, thank you